# nginx on debian 8: multiple locations with and without php

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I'm working on a debian 8 with PHP7 and nginx 1.11.10. I own a VPS and a domain name.

What I'm trying to do seems very simple : I have 2 websites to bind to my domain via nginx.

Let's assume that one is under `/var/www/web1` and the other in `/var/www/web2`. The first is just a ng2 app and the second one needs php.

**My issue is that I can't get PHP-FPM working, I always encounter a 502: Bad Gateway issue ([already checked this](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/nginx-502-bad-gateway-errors-php-fpm/)).**

I think there are 2 ways to solve this : using sub-domains and using sub-locations.

### Using locations

This is one of the conf I've tried:

```
server {
    listen 80;


    root /var/www/web1;
    index  index.html index.php index.htm;

    # static js / html / css files
    location / {
        #root /var/www/lazycoding.io;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # needs PHP
    location /web2 {
        alias /var/www/web2;
        #root /var/www/web2;
        #index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #include        fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

It seems better to me to specify `root` only in `location` but that doesn't work. This is why I'm currently trying to use `alias`. Path to php-fpm socket is correct, permissions also seem right:

```
> ls -lFa /run/php
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  80 Mar 15 21:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 21 root     root     760 Mar 15 23:41 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       5 Mar 15 21:35 php7.0-fpm.pid
srw-rw----  1 www-data www-data   0 Mar 15 21:35 php7.0-fpm.sock=
```

### Using subdomains

Another way (more sexy) to do this would be to use subdomains.

- **mydomain.com** redirects to web1
- **sub.mydomain.com** redirects to web2 (using php)

In this configuration, it seems that I need two server blocks, each with one `location /` with the previously given properties set.

In this configuration, only *mydomain.com* responds whereas both subdomains return 404 errors.

---

In both cases, both nginx and php-fpm services are running well. Also, I always test nginx's configuration with `nginx -t` and I restart services when changes are made.

I'm not experienced with nginx / web server configuration and I don't know which way is the best one.

I'm re-writing my older conf files to add more details to this post but maybe there are some huge errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is named based virtual hosting where you have 2 domains that share the same ip address and port. Here is an example of how you would set that up with in your nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  sub.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/sub.mydomain.com/public_html/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Then you will need to set up **php-fpm** and then configure the server to use that to handle the php requests.

Comment: I've tried this configuration, I think my issue is more about php-fpm's configuration than setting up multiple server blocks / subdomains. I'll update my post soon, sorry !